# In Mercurial, is there a setting to always push new branches?

Tags: mercurial, branch

When using Mercurial, often I'll do `hg push` and I'll get this error message:

```
(use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches)
```

Which is fine, I understand why I get the message. But I **always** want to push any new branches so I was wondering if there was any way to force Mercurial to remember to always push new branches without me having to do:

```
hg push
... 
(use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches)
---
hg push --new-branch
```

Answer (score 3):

There was a way of setting default options for commands on mercurial using the `[default]` section on `.hgrc`, but it is now [deprecated](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Defaults).

The recommended way of doing that is using [aliases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AliasExtension). On your `.hgrc`, put:

```
[alias]
pushb = push --new-branch
```

After that use `hg pushb` to push creating new branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alias in your `.bashrc`:

Example:

`alias hgp="hg push --new-branch"`

Then `hgp` will always successfully push the code.